# Google Analytics Retrieve Starred Profiles via API

Tags: google-analytics-api

Is it possible to retrieve a list of `ga_account_id` and `ga_profile_id` from only the 'starred' profiles by my analytics account programatically?

I've read through the API docs and can't see how this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/) . I strongly recommend the [account summary's report](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/#Account%20Summaries) as its just one request and will return everything you need.

```
GET  /management/accountSummaries
```